# can't get height of object in chrome

Tags: jquery, get, height

i want to get the height property of a object:

```
$('.selector img').each(function(index,e){   
    thisImage = $('#topContent img').get(index);
}
```

so long no problem, but then i want to get the height like this:

```
thisImage.height;
```

i thought it was equvivilent to:

```
thisImage.height();
```

or:

```
thisImage.css("height");
```

but neither does work for me.

And the greatest problem is that

```
thisImage.height;
```

Dose not work in chrome.

Have i missed something or is this a known bug? is there another way to get the height in chrome?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Specifically the object returned by `get()` is going to be the actual DOMElement not the jQuery object so you need to wrap it in jq. like `$(thisImage).height()` or use the actual selector as Catfish suggests.

Answer (score 1):

try

```
var thisImage = $('#topContent img').height();
```

Comment: i was a bit unclear but i need to iterate trough several object